# Anyone knows how to convert a cv::Mat into a NSString?

Tags: objective-c, opencv, format

I am using OpenCV in a iPhone project. In this application, I receive a 3x3 matrix from the Opencv function an need to transform it into a NSString. For example:

```
cv::Mat myMatrix = opencvClass.getMatrix();
NSString *matrixString = myMatrix.toNSString(); // this function does not exist actually but it is what I need
```

Any suggestions?

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you could [convert it to a `std::stringstream`](http://answers.opencv.org/question/12/how-to-convert-cvmat-to-stdstring/), extract the C array of bytes from it and use this to contruct your `NSString` :

```
NSString NSStringFromCvMat(cv::Mat mat)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    ss << mat;
    return [NSString stringWithCString:ss.str().c_str() encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
}
```

Untested but should work. The encoding could be a problem. Maybe try [different values](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000154-BAJJAICE).

I don't think it is the best solution though, and you could find a beter and cleaner one by diving into OpenCV source code.

Comment: It did work for me. 

It may not be the cleanest way but I am using just a 3x3 matrix so the performance won't be badly affected.

Thanks very much =)

Comment: and it's vice versa, if you do this please post